# Windows 8 laptop keeps alternating between the Windows 8 bootloader and Grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-8

I have a Toshiba Portege Z935 with Windows 8 pre-installed. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 with an EFI Boot Partition.

When I turn my computer on, it will boot into Grub2 and I can access both operating systems properly. If I restart the computer again it will  show the Windows 8 bootloader and give me the option of booting into Windows 8 or Ubuntu.

The Windows 8 option works properly but when I try to log into Ubuntu, it gives an error pointing to the file name `\NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr` and says it can't find a required file. Once I go into Windows 8 and the restart the computer, it switches to Grub2 again. In this same way every time I boot the computer  it keeps alternating between Grub2 and the Windows 8 loader comes up.

I'm trying to find a way to either get Grub 2 to launch all the time, or at least get the Ubuntu entry in the Windows 8 Loader to work properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get  the`\NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr` message in grub2 or the windows boot?

Comment: I get that message only when I choose the Ubuntu entry in the Windows boot, Grub 2 works perfectly

Comment: you should be able to go into the bios and select the ubuntu partition as your boot partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s `Recommended Repair` from an Ubuntu disc. This should fix the issue. Indicate the URL that will appear if any problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go into the BIOS and select the Ubuntu partition as your boot partition:

You can do this. by hitting one of the f keys (I never remember which - I think each PC is different anyway) as your computer is restarting. You just select your primary boot partition as the one you want.

Comment: There isn't an option for selecting different partitions, my computer only allows you to choose between HDD, USB, and other media.

Comment: You should be able to do this. What does the 'other media' bit cover?